# Convert a regex expression to erlang's re syntax?

Tags: regex, erlang

I am having hard time trying to convert the following regular expression into an erlang syntax.

What I have is a test string like this:

`1,2 ==> 3 #SUP: 1 #CONF: 1.0`

And the regex that I created with regex101 is this (see below):

`([\d,]+).*==>\s*(\d+)\s*#SUP:\s*(\d)\s*#CONF:\s*(\d+.\d+)`

[image: Regex]:

But I am getting weird match results if I convert it to erlang - here is my attempt:

```
{ok, M} = re:compile("([\\d,]+).*==>\\s*(\\d+)\\s*#SUP:\\s*(\\d)\\s*#CONF:\\s*(\\d+.\\d+)").
re:run("1,2 ==> 3 #SUP: 1 #CONF: 1.0", M).
```

Also, I get more than four matches. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the regex101 version:
https://regex101.com/r/xJ9fP2/1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know much about `erlang`, but I will try to explain. With your regex

```
>{ok, M} = re:compile("([\\d,]+).*==>\\s*(\\d+)\\s*#SUP:\\s*(\\d)\\s*#CONF:\\s*(\\d+.\\d+)").
>re:run("1,2 ==> 3 #SUP: 1 #CONF: 1.0", M).                                                  
{match,[{0, 28},{0,3},{8,1},{16,1},{25,3}]}
         ^^ ^^
         || ||
         || Total number of matched characters from starting index
   Starting index of match
```

**Reason for more than four groups**

First match ***always*** indicates the entire string that is matched by the ***complete*** regex and rest here are the four captured groups you want. So there are total 5 groups.

```
([\\d,]+).*==>\\s*(\\d+)\\s*#SUP:\\s*(\\d)\\s*#CONF:\\s*(\\d+.\\d+)
<------->         <---->             <--->              <--------->
First group    Second group       Third group           Fourth group
<----------------------------------------------------------------->
This regex matches entire string and is first match you are getting
                      (Zero'th group)
```

**How to find desired answer**

Here we want anything except the first group (*which is entire match by regex*). So we can use `all_but_first` to avoid the first group

```
> re:run("1,2 ==> 3 #SUP: 1 #CONF: 1.0", M, [{capture, all_but_first, list}]).                
{match,["1,2","3","1","1.0"]}
```

More info can be found **[here](http://erlang.org/doc/man/re.html#run-3)**

Answer (score 0):

If you are in doubt what is content of the string, you can print it and check out:

```
1> RE = "([\\d,]+).*==>\\s*(\\d+)\\s*#SUP:\\s*(\\d)\\s*#CONF:\\s*(\\d+.\\d+)".
"([\\d,]+).*==>\\s*(\\d+)\\s*#SUP:\\s*(\\d)\\s*#CONF:\\s*(\\d+.\\d+)"
2> io:format("RE: /~s/~n", [RE]).
RE: /([\d,]+).*==>\s*(\d+)\s*#SUP:\s*(\d)\s*#CONF:\s*(\d+.\d+)/
```

For the rest of issue, there is great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37452862/49197) by [rock321987](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1996394/rock321987).